# TEMPLATE_DIRS and templates folder help please

Tags: django, templates, url

So I'm pulling apart a website with the front-end already built and have taken on the task of building out the backend, but I am new to django. I have managed to separate everything out accordingly (css, js, img's in a static folder, html files in a templates folder, etc) and so far have been able to set the index.html as the homepage to django. Within this index.html file, other html files (located in the templates folder along with the index.html file) are being loaded within  tags of the index.html file. Currently all of the images, css, and js is coming through in the file, but the html files are not. I am referencing these html files as "name of file.html" However, I cannot seem to get these to load unless I move the templates folder into the static folder (alongside the css, images, js, etc.) and change the reference to "static/templates/name of file.html"

My project setup is as follows. Also I'm running django 1.7.

```
    atmos_v4/
        atmos_v4/
           init__.py
           settings.py
           urls.py
           wsgi.py
        db.sqlite3
        manage.py
        static/
             css/
                 ...
             img/
                 ...
             js/
                 ...
             media/
                 ...
        templates/
             index.html
                 ...
```

My urls.py and settings.py are below. I have a feeling my TEMPLATE_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT may be set up incorrectly. If not, would someone be so kind as to tell me what I'm missing? Thank you!

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for atmos_v4 project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y=3ey3sv8lm1j358(2bgthtx0bzy_cjaxug@2npx029nfs@5i%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

 INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'atmos_v4.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'atmos_v4.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

from os.path import join

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView 


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

index.html reference examples

```
    <div id="wheelartist" style="position:absolute; top:131px; left:536px; z-    index:999999;">

    <div id="circleartist" class="circleartist">  
        <a id="homebuttonLink" href="artist_profile.html"><img id="homebutton"     title="Home" src="/static/img/icons/user.png" alt=""></a>
        <a id="msgsbuttonLink" href="messages.html"><img id="msgsButton"     title="Messages" src="/static/img/icons/mail.png" alt=""></a>
        <a id="directorybuttonLink" href="directory.html"><img     id="directoryButton" title="Directory" src="/static/img/icons/book.png" alt="">    </a>
        <a id="cartbuttonLink" href="shopping_cart.html"><img id="cartButton"     class="shopingCart" title="Shopping Cart" src="/static/img/icons/shopping.png"     alt=""></a>
        <a id="contestsbuttonLink" href="contests_list.html"><img     id="contestsButton" class="planet" title="Planet"     src="/static/img/icons/planet.png" alt=""></a>
        <a id="pointsbuttonLink" href="points.html"><img id="pointsButton"     class="awards" title="Awards" src="/static/img/icons/awards.png" alt=""></a>
        <a id="prefbuttonLink" href="preferences.html"><img id="prefButton"     class="tools" title="Tools" src="/static/img/icons/tools.png" alt=""></a>
        <a id="searchbuttonLink" href="search.html"><img id="searchButton" class="headphones" title="Search" src="/static/img/icons/music.png" alt=""></a>        
        <a id="mapbuttonLink" href="artist_careermap.html"><img id="mapButton" title="Career Map" src="/static/img/icons/map.png" alt=""></a>
        <a id="profitsbuttonLink" href="artist_profits.html"><img id="profitsButton" title="Profits" src="/static/img/icons/profits.png" alt=""></a>
        <a id="statsbuttonLink" href="artist_stats.html"><img id="statsButton" title="Stats" src="/static/img/icons/stats.png" alt=""></a>  </div>
```

Comment: ***Within this index.html file, other html files (located in the templates folder along with the index.html file) are being loaded within div tags of the index.html file.

Comment: You need to setup the URLs for all of those pages...

Comment: You can edit your question to correct that sentence. But I actually have *no idea* what it means - you neglected to post an example of exactly how you're doing this, so the question is unanswerable.

Comment: What I mean is that the site is set up so that separate html pages are being loaded inside of div tags that are in another html file (index.html). I have been able to have the html files load when the templates folder containing said html files is moved into my static folder. However, when the templates folder is set up how I have it above, the html files do not load.

Comment: What do you mean the "html pages are being loaded"? Do you mean they're being linked to? When do you seen an error? What error do you see?

Comment: No, that didn't explain anything. What do you mean by "separate html pages are being loaded inside of div tags". I can't understand that sentence at all. Above you show a simple link. What does that have to do with "loading HTML pages inside a div"?

Comment: Yes rnevius, the html files within the templates folder are simply being linked within the index.html file. I do not see an error. However, when I click a button that is supposed to load the linked html file within the index.html file, nothing happens. I have been able to solve this problem by moving the templates folder within my static folder and changing each link to static/templates/"nameoffile".html, but when I move templates folder to how I have it set now and change the href tag link to "nameoffile".html, I am not able to see the html file. Does anyone know why this would be?

Comment: Because templates are just that, templates: they are things that need to be rendered by a Django view. And a Django view needs to be routed by an entry in urls.py. I'm not sure why you are using Django at all for a bunch of static HTML files.

Comment: As mentioned before, you need to configure the views and URLs for those templates, in a similar way you have done for the main index file.

Answer (score -3):

```
templates/
         index.html
```

try to change to this structure

```
templates/
         atmos_v4/
                  index.html
```

and inside the settings.py remove this
"**from os.path import join**"

EDIT: after you update your file now i see that you have bad index.html file, you need to use the built-in function for templates and url

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#url